# Отказоустойчивый кластер

Tags: windows, сервер, cluster, windows-server-2016

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать отказоустойчивый кластер.Имею 2 виртуальные машины с windows server 2019 и один схд, тоже виртуалка, на базе open media vault. Кластер создать не проблема, но я не понимаю как мне сделать так, что бы данные хранились на схд, прочитав гайды я создал на схд 2 виртуальных жестких диска и установил ISCSI.